# SwiftUI List View Mutiline text overlapping

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

Xcode 12.0 and previous version.
I am trying to make a selectable multiline text list. I don't know if it is a bug but it sure looks like it.

```
   List(selection: $selectedVerse){
        ForEach(versesInChapter(selectedBook ?? "Genesis", selectedChapter ?? 1), id: \.self) { item in
            Text("\(item.verse). \(item.text)")
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
    .padding([.top, .bottom, .trailing]).frame(minWidth: 400.00, idealWidth: 600.00, maxWidth: 900.00)
```

[image]

I can use a scrollview and stack but I can't figure out how to make it selectable.

```
 ScrollView {
     VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing: 7.0){
          ForEach(versesInChapter(selectedBook ?? "Genesis", selectedChapter ?? 1), id: \.self) { item in
               Text("\(item.verse). \(item.text)")
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
           }.frame(alignment: .leading)          
      } 
  }
```

Comment: Is this on macOS?

Comment: yes this is on macOS